# Navigate from parent Activity or from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-navigation

In Android using the Navigation Component you can navigate from an Activity using `findNavController(...).navigate(...)` and from a Fragment using `findNavController().navigate(...)`.

I want to know what's the best practice for the following example using viewModel:

I have 2 fragments, one is the Login that contains the Login form, and the other is the Home fragment; both under a navigation component inside a MainActivity.

LoginFragment -> HomeFragment

When successful (given that I can observe the login action from both), should the MainActivity or the LoginFragment perform the navigate? I know I can do any of these, but I would like to know what is the best practice for this case.

Comment: Their associated nav controllers are exactly the same. So it doesn't matter which one you use

Comment: Hey @Christilyn , thanks for your comment! I know they are the same in a function-wise manner, but what I would like to know if there is some best practice of where this should be done. Is it better to handle the navigation in each fragment or should I centralize it in the Activity?

Comment: If you're going from fragment to fragment. Then you should handle navigation in the fragment itself. It's better if you directly access nav controller rather than creating a communication interface between fragments and activity to centralize navigation - IMO

Comment: Ok, noted! Thank you! Anyway, I will wait for an answer with a link to Android docs or something like that.